# Need help to glue code together

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to learn how to use Partial Views. I have done a simple example application with some gaps that I need help to fill to be able to understand (and also understand whats the point with partial Views) and glue all parts together to be able to run this simple test application. I have read some example about Partial Views, but I do not understand it!

The application just display a list of `First Name` and `Last Name` in a database created with Entity Framework.

Grateful if I can get some help!

The Model Person looks like this:

```
namespace RenderActionTest.Models
{
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
 }
 }
```

The Partial View looks like this:

```
@model RenderActionTest.Models.Person

<tr>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.FirstName)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.LastName)
</td>
</tr>
```

The Index View looks like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<RenderActionTest.Models.Person>

<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {

@{ 
    Html.RenderAction(" ?? ", " ?? ");
 }

 }

 </table>
```

And finally the Controller looks like this:

```
    // GET: Persons
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
    var person = new Person();

       // return View(db.People.ToList());
     return PartialView(" ?? ", person);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking forward from your given sample code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
 @{ 
    Html.RenderAction(" ?? ", " ?? ");
  }
}
```

Think of Partials as HTML code snippet (like .ascx) and need to embed in your view. There are four ways to render a partials/Actions in parent view in Razor view engine.

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Controller/_Partial.cshtml", item);} // from your example
```

Use RenderPartial when you have a model to send to the view and there will be a lot of html that doesn't need to be stored in a variable. `@Html.RenderPartial` returns the equivalent of a .ascx user control. It gets its own copy of the page's ViewDataDictionary and changes made to the RenderPartial's ViewData do not effect the parent's ViewData.

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Controller/_Partial.cshtml", item) // from your example
```

Like `RenderPartial` method, Partial method is also useful when the displaying data in the partial view is already in the corresponding view model. 
`@Html.Partial` returns a html encoded string that gets constructed inline with the parent. It accesses the parent's model.

```
@{Html.Action("ActionReturningPartialView","ControllerWhereActionResides");}
```

Use Action when you do not have a model to send to the view and have a little bit of text to bring back that needs to be stored in a variable.

```
@{Html.RenderAction("ActionReturningPartialView","ControllerWhereActionResides");}
```

Use `RenderAction` when you do not have a model to send to the view and have a lot of html to bring back that doesn't need to be stored in a variable.

`RenderAction` and `RenderPartial` are faster.

Hope above details will help you identify when you actually need an action method and when you can simply just render the partial without requiring the Action method.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your controller:

`PartialView()`expects the location of your partial view as the first parameter, so it would be something like

```
PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_MyPartialView.cshtml", ...)
```

Regarding your list view:

`Html.RenderAction()` is not the correct extension method your are searching for as it is for rendering links refering to an action in a controller. What you are searching for is `Html.RenderPartial("PersonPartialView", person)`.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

You can just call

```
Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/PartialViewName.cshtml",item);
```

Or

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/PartialViewName.cshtml",item);
```

Instead of calling render action.
In your example you are not really working with partial view thus you can also `return View("~/Views/Shared/PartialViewName.cshtml",person)` in the Index.
In case you will still want to use renderAction you need to call it like
 `Html.RenderAction("Index", "ControllerName");`

Comment: Thanks for the info!